# How do I select columns " from the below schema?

Tags: apache-spark-sql

Read a JSON file and registered a temporary table with the below schema(inferred from JSON file with Native Spark SQL inference).

```
df = spark.read.json('/path/to/json', multiLine=True)
babynames.registerTempTable("babynames")
```

Now I would like to select columns

```
"sid", "id", "position", "created_at", "created_meta", "updated_at", "updated_meta", "meta", "year", "first_name", "county", "sex", "count"
```

using Spark SQL select statement.

Here is the data source: https://data.cityofnewyork.us/api/views/25th-nujf/rows.json?accessType=DOWNLOAD

Comment: can you post what you have tried to make that work? Are you stuck or getting some errors? If yes can you provide that.

Comment: Please don't make more work for other people by vandalizing your posts. By posting on the Stack Exchange network, you've granted a non-revocable right, under the [CC BY-SA 4.0 license](//creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/4.0/), for Stack Exchange to distribute that content (i.e. regardless of your future choices). By Stack Exchange policy, the non-vandalized version of the post is the one which is distributed. Thus, any vandalism will be reverted. If you want to know more about deleting a post please see: [How does deleting work?](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/5221)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Once you have the json file located at specific location you can read the column names as under but you need to have a better understanding of the json elements.

Using spark Sql :

```
val df = spark.read.option("multiline",true).json("/path/to/json")
df.createOrReplaceTempView("TestTable")
val selectedColumnsDf = spark.sql(""" Select meta.view.columns.id ,meta.view.columns.position, meta.view.createdAt  from TestTable """)
```

Using DataFrame Api it can be done as below :

```
val df = spark.read.option("multiline",true).json("/path/to/json")
val selectedColumnsDf = df.select("meta.view.columns.id","meta.view.columns.position","meta.view.createdAt")
```

I am just selecting the three columns just to give you an idea. you can add remaining columns as per your requirement.